# How to combine IF and REGEXP_CONTAINS in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am fairly new to BigQuery and SQL. I am trying to figure out if it is possible to combine IF and REGEXP_Contains.

I want to apply different calculations based on a campaign name.

So If Campaign Name contains 'ABC' THEN, (A + C) As Cost, if Campaign Name is Not 'ABC' Then, (A + B + C) As Cost.

I tried this:

CASE
IF REGEXP_CONTAINS(lower(CampaignName),'ABC'),(A + C), (A+B+C) END AS Cost,

But got this error message:

Syntax error: Expected "(" but got identifier "REGEXP_CONTAINS"

What have I done wrong here?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done two way using If() or case as below:

```
IF (REGEXP_CONTAINS(CampaignName,'ABC'),(A + C), (A+B+C) ) AS Cost
```

or

```
case when REGEXP_CONTAINS(CampaignName,'ABC') then (A+C) ELSE 
(A+B+C) END AS Cost
```